# AWS (node.js): How can I retrieve a listener ARN from a Load Balancer using just ALB ARN?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services

I've got a list of load balancer ARNs which need their certificates swapped from an old one which expires soon to a new one. I've written a script that does this successfully for non-ELBv2 LBs, but v2 types are causing me a headache since I can't seem to programmatically match a listener (or listeners) to a LB ARN. I know that once I have that listener ARN, I can use:

```
elbv2.modifyListener(params,(err, data) => {<snip>});
```

and expect a response, but getting to that point is eluding me. I've tried elbv2.describeLoadBalancers(), but that appears to require a listener ARN in the params.

So, how do I give AWS an LB ARN and get its associated listener ARN(s)?

Comment: If you know which certificates are expiring, why not iterate all listeners and see if they are using those certificates? Also, you can request a certificate that's managed by Amazon. Those are automatically renewed for you.

Comment: In case it wasn't totally obvious, I'm still very new to AWS :) 

Thanks for the idea! I hadn't considered that this was even a possibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for [`describeListeners()`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/ELBv2.html#describeListeners-property). The documentation says:

> Describes the specified listeners or **the listeners for the specified Application Load Balancer or Network Load Balancer**. You must specify **either** a load balancer or one or more listeners.

So if you call it with just `LoadBalancerArn`, you should get a list of listeners attached to that load balancer.

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var elbv2 = new AWS.ELBv2();
var params = {
  LoadBalancerArn: 'arn:...'
};
elbv2.describeListeners(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
  else     console.log(data);           // successful response
});
```

Comment: What did you import to use describeListeners?

Comment: @user1633146 just the normal `aws-sdk`. Check out the updated answer.

Comment: Is it possible to use the aws-sdk and the aws-cdk together? I was using aws-cdk but can not find a way to pass the loadbalancerarn to get the list of listeners.